# Setting the monomial degree in z3py

Tags: z3, z3py

When reasoning about polynomial inequalities, Z3 seems to have to first transform the polynomial into monomial form. I'm wondering if there's a setting in the solver that let me define the monomial degree I want my polynomials to be transformed to?

I'm using the z3py interface and I can't find it by searching online.

Answer (score 0):

No, Z3 does not have this setting.